# How can I create a custom property in Blender that affects a circle?

Tags: modeling, custom-properties

I created a circle in Blender.

In Object Mode I did: *Add > Mesh > Circle* and also added more vertices. Then pressed <kbd>F</kbd> in Edit Mode and it filled the circle.

Now on the right side of the window I select *Object* and in the object window below I click on *+New* to create a new custom property. When the new property is created, it is of type Float and I have named it "Fill Amount". I want to use this property to control the fill amount of the circle.

The problem now is how to connect the new custom property to affect the circle amount when the float value is changed?

If I now change the values on the right-hand side of the new user-defined property, nothing changes in the circle.

[image: circle with custom property Fill Amount on the right]

Comment: Presumably you'd need to add a custom driver written in python to control it, but what do you actually mean by "fill amount"? - Blender itself won't have a clue what you mean unless you tell it what to do with the value! (I don't know python but assume that's how it should be done.)

Comment: @JohnEason by fill amount i mean to control how much the circle will be filled when changing the custom property float value.  I pressed F key to fill the circle now I want to be able to control how much to fill it by the custom property.  later I want to use the custom property in unity.  but for now I want to use it first in blender.  fill amount i mean if the value is 0 it will look like a ring if the value is 1 the circle will be filled like in the image.  and the values between 0 and 1 or maybe the range should be 0 to 100 will be the amount of how much the circle will be filled.

Comment: @JohnEason and you right my problem is how to tell blender to do it.

Comment: Yes, but fill inwards, i.e: using extrude then Scale and dragging the mouse, or filling by quadrant, or some other method? If you used the first method you'd also have to merge all the verts at the centre when you reached 100, and you'd need to use a formula using the circle radius multiplied by the percentage to calculate how far inwards to scale. Not as easy as it sounds and you'd have to work out how to do the same in Unity if you're just exporting the custom value!

Answer (score 1):

Such interface can be programmed in Geonodes:

[image]

Comment: How did you get the Fill Amount in the Geometry Nodes ?  on the right side I clicked the Modifiers >  Add Modifier > Geometry Nodes > clicked on New and it added Geometry Nodes 001 but where is the Fill amount ?  I created the Fill Amount custom property in the Object tab.  how did you get it to the Geometry Nodes in the Modifiers?

Comment: @Jack By default, the geometry node modifier has only a geometry input, so if you want to add more of them you have to do it yourself in the node editor. Here you can see that the Fill amount value is connected to the math node divide, which is used to control the size the top of the cone

Comment: @Alex i saw that and i could make this not like he did but i wonder because in my blender the Fill Amount was not on the right side under the Geometry Nodes I created the custom property Fill Amount in tab Object and added to it a driver but how he brought it to the Geometry Nodes ?  when i create Group Input the name inside is Geometry not Fill Amount.  and then when I put line from the Group Input to add a node I searched for Divide but there is no Divide so I had to do Add > Utilities > Math > Math.

Comment: @Jack I suggest you watch a few YT videos about using geometry nodes. The Math node has a dropdown on it where you can select many different types of mathmatical functions. The only problem is that you can't export unapplied modifiers from Blender so you're not going to be able to use geonodes in external progams like Unity for instance.